# Android access raw file inside class without Context (non- Activity)

Tags: android, file-io, applicationcontext

I have a code inside myActivity.class

```
InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String s;
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
try    
{  while((s = buff.readLine()) != null)
       {
           list.add(s);
       }

} catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I want to move that part of code to separate java.class, but here I face a problem, how I can to access a raw file by InputStream without using getApplicationContext()?

For instance:

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<String>
{

private InputStream in = ???; // how to declare InpuStream without Context???
private BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));;
private String s;
private MyArrayList array;

public MyArrayList ()
{
    try
    {
        while ((s = buff.readLine()) != null)
          {
            array.add(s);
          }

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

I have tried
     `InputStream in = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.text);` but it gave me NullPointerException

So my question is: Does exist some way to initialize InputStream with raw file outside Activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can to access a raw file by InputStream without using getApplicationContext()?

First, you do not need `getApplicationContext()` in your existing code. Deleting it will work just fine, and it saves an unnecessary call.

Beyond that -- and assuming that you *really* think that an `ArrayList` should be responsible for I/O -- `MyArrayList` needs you to pass in one of the following:

- the `InputStream`, or
- the `Resources` (so you can call `openRawResource()` on it), or
- a suitable `Context` (so you can call `getResources()` on it) (and which, depending on the lifetime of `MyArrayList`, could be one of [several possible objects](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/))

Comment: Yes, I resolved an issue by putting in `MyArrayList (InputStream in)`, but my question was about initializing InputStream with raw file directly inside separate non-Activity class, in my case inside MyArrayList.class. Thank you for your advise, I don't need indeed getApplicationContext()

Comment: @VictorG: "my question was about initializing InputStream with raw file directly inside separate non-Activity class" -- that is not possible, unless the non-Activity class has access to the `Resources` or a `Context` from which it can get the `Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access App resources without current app context. If you want to move code in diff Java file simply Make a class and inside that class make a function with activity as one of the function's parameter and your required return type.
As activity is parent for context we can use it where ever we need activity or context reference out side the activity class.

```
public class Demo{

public static "whatEverReturnTypeYouNeedToReturnFromFunction" f1(Activity act, ...){
InputStream inputStream = act.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String s;
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
try    
{  while((s = buff.readLine()) != null)
       {
           list.add(s);
       }

} catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return whatEverReturnTypeYouNeedToReturnFromFunction;
}
}
}
```

In the above code make variables static as our function is static.
And to call it from Activity class simply call

```
Type "whateverYouWhatToGetFromFunction" = Demo.f1(this, ...);
```